# Can't seem to render partial view - controller not being hit

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, partial-views

I have a drop down list that I want to render a partial view depending on what item is chosen. For this, I am using jquery and MVC 5. After having put breakpoints in my controller, my Url.Action() call doesn't seem to be getting there when I change the dropdown selection. I'm not sure I understand how to use route values correctly so that could be it. This is what I've got:

**Relevant part of starting view**

```
<div>
        @if (role == "admin")
         {
            <p>Choose state to view:</p>
            <select id="stateList">
                <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
                <option value="AR">Arkansas</option>
                <option value="DE">Delaware</option>
                <option value="FL">Florida</option>
                <option value="GA">Georgia</option>
                <option value="IA">Iowa</option>
                <option value="IL">Illinois</option>
                <option value="IN">Indiana</option>
                <option value="KS">Kansas</option>
                <option value="KY">Kentucky</option>
                <option value="LA">Louisiana</option>
                <option value="MD">Maryland</option>
                <option value="MS">Mississippi</option>
                <option value="MO">Missouri</option>
                <option value="NC">North Carolina</option>
                <option value="NE">Nebraska</option>
                <option value="NJ">New Jersey</option>
                <option value="OH">Ohio</option>
                <option value="OK">Oklahoma</option>
                <option value="SC">South Carolina</option>
                <option value="TN">Tennessee</option>
                <option value="TX">Texas</option>
                <option value="VA">Virginia</option>
                <option value="WV">West Virginia</option>
            </select>
            <div id="#partialPlaceHolder">

            </div>
        }
```

**JQuery to get to controller**

```
//Load partial view when an admin changes the state selection
    $('#stateList').change(function () {
        var selection = $(this).val();
        var url = '@Url.Action("StateData", "Visualizations")' + '?StateID=' + selection;
        //url ends up looking like this: /Visualizations/StateData?StateID=IA  (or some other state abbreviation)
        $("#partialPlaceHolder").load(url, function () {
                console.log("it worked");
         });
      });
```

**Model**

```
public class VisualizationModels
{
    public String StateID { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller for generating partial view**

```
public ActionResult StateData(string stateID)
    {
        VisualizationModels vm = new VisualizationModels();
        vm.StateID = stateID;
        return PartialView("_SpecificStateData", vm);
    }
```

**UPDATE**

Oddly enough, if I use `$.get` instead of `@Url.Action`, I will actually hit the controller action, it just won't render the partial view now for some reason...

```
//Load partial view when an admin changes the state selection
    $('#stateList').change(function () {
        var selection = $(this).val();
        var url = '/Visualizations/StateData?StateID=' + selection;
        $.get(url, function (data) {
            $('#partialPlaceHolder').html(data);
        });
```

Comment: I don't think @Url.Action is valid razor syntax within a javascript block. Have you tried F12, network tab in your browser? It captures all server requests.

Comment: @OleEHDufour I'm not sure about that as I use @Url.Action in a piece of javascript right before this one and it works fine. I have a line that does `window.location = '@Url.Action("DownloadDocuments", "Visualizations")';` that allows you to download a zip file, seems to work ok. I just checked the network tab though and nothing appears to come through for the code in my original post which is suspicious. For the line I just posted in this comment, that one does come through on the Network tab.

Comment: As long as the javascript is in the razor view and not a separate .js file it should work. Is the event handler code wrapped in `$(function() {  });` to make sure the document is ready before attaching handlers?

Comment: @MKF, ok. What is the return code on the network tab? (400,500?) And what is the  name of the class of StateData method? Should be VisualizationController...

Comment: @akerra I do indeed have it wrapped in `$(document).ready(function(){}` - good thought though.

Comment: @OleEHDufour Nothing is returned, the network tab is completely clear. It's like there is no request being made at all. Name of the class is indeed VisualizationsController.

Comment: Added an update to original post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out... it's the stupidest, peskiest little issue. In my main view (at the top of my original post) I had typed the `id` of my `div` wrong...

Wrong:

```
<div id="#partialPlaceHolder"></div>
```

Right:

```
<div id="partialPlaceHolder"></div>
```

Everything is working as expected now. Final JS looks like this:

```
//Load partial view when an admin changes the state selection
    $('#stateList').change(function () {
        var selection = $(this).val();
        var url = '@Url.Action("StateData", "Visualizations", new { StateID = "_state" })'.replace("_state", selection);
        $("#partialPlaceHolder").load(url, function () {
                console.log("it worked");
        });
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

Cannot you use something like this

```
 var url = '@Url.Action("StateData", "Visualizations", new { StateID = selection})'
```

instead of

```
 var url = '@Url.Action("StateData", "Visualizations")' + '?StateID=' + selection;
```

and check if this is working. Because if your parameter would not be passed correctly. Your route handler will not able to map correct action method.

Comment: when I try that I get a red squiggly under `selection` that says "The name 'selection' does not exist in the current context"

Comment: I attempted this `var url = '@Url.Action("StateData", "Visualizations", new { StateID = "_state"})'.replace("_state", selection);` and the red squiggle disappears but it still doesn't work.